# In Ant, copy all files from a tree of folders into a single folder?

Tags: ant, copy, directory

Is it possible to use Ant to copy all the files (not folders) from a hierarchy of folders into one destination folder?

For instance, I have a tree like this:

```
res
|-images
|  |-fg.png
|  +-bg.png
+-sounds
   +-music.mp3
```

And I would like a result like this:

```
data
|-fg.png
|-bg.png
+-music.mp3
```

The way things are named, filename conflicts are not an issue.

Is this possible to do with Ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `flatten` attribute of the `copy` task to accomplish this. You can read more at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html.

Comment: Thanks. I also added includeEmptyDirs="false" so that the flattened directories weren't copied.